# Qt Visual Studio Debug error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opencv

I am facing an error for the past two days with Qt and more specifically with qglobal.cpp.

[image]

I'm developping an application with Qt of course, as well as OpenCV and this error came out from no where and I just don't why it is there.
Let me precise that when ignoring the Error, the program works just fine

Does anyone already had this kind of message ?

My configuration is the following:

- QT: 4.8.1
- Win 7 32 bits
- Visual Studio 2008
- OpenCV 2.8

Thank you for your help

Comment: Press Retry, break into debugger, in stack view open the topmost frame that contains your code and inspect variables. It may be that some of the objects are deleted or corrupted.

Comment: Does that happen before anything else appears on the screen or after something has popped up?  If it is the former, you have a race condition.

Comment: @cup This happens before anything appears on the screen. What's a race condition ?

Comment: @Paul I just found the error thanks to your advice. When going to the stack view I just saw that there was a problem with a widget initialization. Thank you very much that was just what I was looking for

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition